# What is this type of UI component called?

Tags: web-development, user-interface, ios

What is this kind of UI component called? I think it makes more sense in certain cases than a set of radio buttons and I'd like to create a similar component for a web app I'm developing. I just want to know what it's called in case someone out there has created some nice JavaScript way to implement this sort of component. Right now I wouldn't know what to search for, though.

[image]

Comment: Here's another, perhaps better example: http://www.megaleecher.net/uploads/iphone-vpn-configuration.png

Comment: It's called *mutually exclusive option selection apparatus*.

Comment: The referenced screenshot is iOS, but the same control exists on OS X as well (see my comment to accepted answer), so it's not off topic, despite the tagging and description.

Comment: See here for an [iOS UI Catalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think there is a standard name.

It looks similar to what apple call a **segmented control**.

(See http://idevrecipes.com/category/uisegmentedcontrol/ for a picture)

Comment: Now YOU seem to be the most correct so far. And this is the first answer that I can plug into Google Image Search and have most of the results be the actual thing I was originally talking about.

Comment: [OS X reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using that name.

Answer (score 2):

iglvzx is right. In fact, it resembles closely the type of car radio buttons from which the name for the UI components was derived

[Why Radio Button is called a Radio Button | knowAhead](http://www.knowahead.in/dyk/how-radio-button-got-its-name/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to a **radio button**, there is also a GUI component known as a **toggle button**. Both types of buttons can be added to a **button group** so only one button in the group can be selected at a time. This is in contrast to a **tab**, which is attached to a **panel**.

Comment: Hmm, you would seem to be the most correct so far.

Comment: Why does it have to be visually attached to a panel for it be considered a tab? It behaves the exact same, does it not?

Comment: I concur with iglvzx.

Answer (score 0):

I would call that a [tab bar](http://www.significantpixels.com/2011/04/04/the-iphone-tab-bar/), simply styled to fit into the rest of the application UI. All of the tabs generally have the same data presented in different ways, but it's still just a group of views which are changed out based on a tab selection.

Comment: @Darth, Notice what Jason has actually circled. The tab bar is not the group of three buttons.

Comment: @iglvzx I would call both a tab bar - While I agree with your answer on how it's technically constructed, on a more abstract level the use of toggle-able GUI elements, of which only one may be selected, and the selection of one *changes the content of another component on the interface* is a tab component, regardless of whether it's constructed from radio buttons or toggle buttons or if the tabs appear connected to the buttons. [Here](http://photos.appleinsider.com/Aqua.Speechpane.png) is a better example of what I meant to link.

Comment: No, the [tab bar](http://www.significantpixels.com/2011/04/04/the-iphone-tab-bar/) is like what is at the bottom of iTunes.  Although they're functionally kind of equivalent (in the sense that they're basically radio buttons), the tab bar is meant to switch out an entire screen, while the segmented control usually _chooses_ something, without changing the screen.

Comment: @bobobobo Uh, the segmented control at the bottom of the calendar app (as shown in the picture in the question).... changes out the entire screen.

Comment: Ok, but it is still not a tab bar -- [see the iOS UI catalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html) (search for "tab bar", then search for "segmented control")